# Grab Body contents and wrap it within an element to show sort of like an iframe

Tags: jquery, document-body

Ok, so I need all of the html within the body tag to be wrapped within a `<div class="wrap" />` that lives within the body tag (deep within it).  This code needs to run from within the `<body>` tag itself, so am thinking we'll need to append the code to the head or add it after the first `<script>` tag and run it from there.

I want it to basically output the entire body contents into the div with a class of `wrap` on that same page (within the body), with scrollbars as needed ofcourse, so `overflow: auto;` and will most likely need to use `.wrapInner`, but am not sure how to handle it completely. So it should than be inserted into the `<div class="wrap" />` and will sort of mimic the idea of an iframe, but not exactly.

Comment: what is the problem if the script element is moved to the `wrap` elemnt

Comment: Yeah, that might actually work... hmmm, but than would it be better to create the wrap element dynamically with code (from within the body), or have it be a part of the DOM from the start (from within the body)?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized now that I need to put it in an element that is already within the DOM... arggg!  How to do that, with an element that is already a part of the body... <div class="wrap"> is already within the body, can't remove it with HTML, as I need everything to be in it.  I can detach it I suppose with jQuery and than reattach it afterwards... would that work?  Using `.detach()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you need to use [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('body').wrapInner('<div class="wrap" />')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mjCFu/)

For your second question: would it be better to create the wrap element dynamically with code (from within the body), or have it be a part of the DOM from the start (from within the body)?

It will always be better if you change the markup than to modify the dom using script later

Comment: Thanks, your code got me started.  I found a solution. :)  I don't know why but I was thinking that the code would be called again and again and again, weird huh?  The document only loads once... Brain Fart I suppose!